# Delphi with __android_log_write

Tags: android, delphi, logging

I want to write on the Android log, with Embarcadero® Delphi.
I used:

```
uses
    ...,Androidapi.Log;

__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, 'TAG', 'TimerWifi');
```

No compilation error, the program runs, but **no lines in the log**!

What is wrong?

Comment: Looks OK to me - what are you using to view the log?

Comment: On which Android version are you working on? Based on [Android logging documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging) there are many more functions related to logging that are not implemented in Delphi's `Androidapi.Log` unit. For instance when reading through Android logging documentation I can find functions like [__android_log_is_loggable](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging#__android_log_is_loggable) that checks to determine if a log message with a given priority and tag will be printed. ...

Comment: ... It is possible that your application doesn't have set proper `minimum_priority` in order to log your message properly. It seems that Android version 30 might have changed how logging works. Unfortunately unit `Androidapi.Log` doesn't seem to be up to date here.

Comment: @DaveNottage I use the Android Log Viewer by SERIALGAMES Inc.

Comment: @SilverWarior The target is on Android 12,  __android_log_is_loggable is not accessible through Delphi

Comment: You might be interested in using code similar to [here](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/blob/d119fd3e0f4a376f86decc8055348c964b7d11a0/Core/DW.OSLog.Android.pas#L49), which uses the Util.Log class, the import of which is [here](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/blob/d119fd3e0f4a376f86decc8055348c964b7d11a0/API/DW.Androidapi.JNI.Util.pas#L332). Using these methods has always worked for me

Comment: @DaveNottage Hello, may be it can works, but I can't make it compile. All references to Kastry environment are missing...

Comment: That's why I said "similar". Of course if you use those units "as-is", you'll need to include the other units from Kastri. I've created a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/DelphiWorlds/352df313c06f1f816ffa30b9492563de) that has just the code that is needed to emit debug log messages.

Comment: @DaveNottage Thank you very much, it's very nice to have taken the time to explain to me how to do it: it works very well!
Thank you also for introducing me to Kastri.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not answer why `__android_log_write` does not appear to work, however I've added this as an alternative since the OP has indicated that this method works for them:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, Androidapi.Helpers;
  
type
  Jutil_LogClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{62108FE8-1DBB-4C4F-A0C7-35D12BD116DC}']
    {class} function _GetASSERT: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetDEBUG: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetERROR: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetINFO: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetVERBOSE: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetWARN: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function d(tag: JString; msg: JString): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function d(tag: JString; msg: JString; tr: JThrowable): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function e(tag: JString; msg: JString): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function e(tag: JString; msg: JString; tr: JThrowable): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function getStackTraceString(tr: JThrowable): JString; cdecl;
    {class} function i(tag: JString; msg: JString): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function i(tag: JString; msg: JString; tr: JThrowable): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function isLoggable(tag: JString; level: Integer): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function println(priority: Integer; tag: JString; msg: JString): Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function v(tag: JString; msg: JString): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function v(tag: JString; msg: JString; tr: JThrowable): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function w(tag: JString; msg: JString): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function w(tag: JString; msg: JString; tr: JThrowable): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function w(tag: JString; tr: JThrowable): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function wtf(tag: JString; msg: JString): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function wtf(tag: JString; tr: JThrowable): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} function wtf(tag: JString; msg: JString; tr: JThrowable): Integer; cdecl; overload;
    {class} property ASSERT: Integer read _GetASSERT;
    {class} property DEBUG: Integer read _GetDEBUG;
    {class} property ERROR: Integer read _GetERROR;
    {class} property INFO: Integer read _GetINFO;
    {class} property VERBOSE: Integer read _GetVERBOSE;
    {class} property WARN: Integer read _GetWARN;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/util/Log')]
  Jutil_Log = interface(JObject)
    ['{6A5EC34E-CB76-4AB0-A11D-7CCB3B40C571}']
  end;
  TJutil_Log = class(TJavaGenericImport<Jutil_LogClass, Jutil_Log>) end;

procedure LogDebug(const ATag, AMsg: string);
begin
  TJutil_Log.JavaClass.d(StringToJString(ATag), StringToJString(AMsg));
end;
```

example:

```
LogDebug('MyApp', 'This is a test message');
```

Similar methods can be written to wrap the others in the imported `Util.Log` class, or a different method entirely written that caters for `d`, `e`, `i`, `w` (for example) where the log level could be passed as a parameter.